# The expression 'x.Taken' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, eager-loading

class Taak :

```
   
        [Key]    
        public int TaakId { get; set; }
        public int Pid { get; private set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(0,23.5)]
        public double Uur { get; private set; }
        [Required]
        public Functie Functie { get; private set; }
        public List<Taak> Taken { get; private set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<WerknemerTaak> Werknemers { get; set; }
```

class WerknemerTaak:

```
  [Required]
        public Werknemer Werknemer { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        public Taak Taak { get; set; }
        
        public Afdelingen Afdeling { get; set; }
        public string Taakbeschrijving { get; set; }
```

ReadAllTakenWthWerknemers :

```
  public List<Werknemer> ReadAllWerknemersWithTaken()
        {
            var taken = ctx.Werknemers
                .Include(x => x.Taken)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Taak)
                .ToList();
            
          
            return taken;
        }
```

Program.cs

```
_mgr.GetAllWerknemersWithTaken().ForEach(x =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("Waarvan de taken zijn:");
                            x.Taken.ToList().ForEach(t =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\t"+t.Taak.ToString());
                            });
                        });
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

> The expression 'x.Taken' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation,
> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

I tried adding Where(t => t.Werknemer.Pid.Equals(t.Taak.Pid))), with no luck at all. I searched for others with same problem, But didn't find an answer for me. And I need to use eager loading.

Comment: What is the data type of ctx.Werknemers? Are you getting runtime error or compile time error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am getting the error at compile time. ctx.Werknemers  is this  public DbSet<Werknemer> Werknemers { get; set; }

Comment: `WerknemerTaak` class does not have Taken property. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no that's not it. it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chetan is correct, you are getting your LINQ expression mixed up, and your entities are a bit intertwined as well that you should look to straighten out. Renamed to make it more readable you can see the issue:

```
var taken = ctx.Werknemers  // <- Query over Werknemers...
    .Include(werknemer => werknemer.Taken) // werknemer has no Taken collection...
    .ThenInclude(taak => taak.Taak)
    .ToList();
```

Changing the "x" term doesn't change the type, it just makes it more readable. When you expand `x.` with intellisense it will outline the properties of the type it is working with.

This expression is against Werknemer entities, *not* Taaks. Wernemers does not include the "Taken" property, Taak does.

This would work:

```
var taken = ctx.Taaks 
    .Include(x => x.Taken)
```

Or from Werknemers, this should work:

```
var taken = ctx.Werknemers  // <- Query over Werknemers...
    .Include(x => x.Taak)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Taken) // <- ThenInclude dives into Taak
```

To make it a bit more readable as to what entity the expression is using:

```
var taken = ctx.Werknemers  // <- Query over Werknemers...
    .Include(werknemer => werknemer.Taak)
    .ThenInclude(taak => taak.Taken)
```

This query would still be selecting Werknemers, where it implies you want the Taken Taaks. To get the Taaks, you would use `SelectMany`.

```
var taken = ctx.Werknemers  
    // Assuming you would have a `Where` clause to filter the Taken taaks from specific Werk/Taaks...
    .SelectMany(werknemer => werknemer.Taak.Taken);
```

To eager load properties of the Taak you would include `Include` etc. after the `SelectMany` based on the Taak navigation properties.

The next issue you will face is the self-referencing loop inside Taak with Taken. Taak will need something like a null-able ParentTaakId or such to facilitate this relationship. For the Taak that will be in the Taken collection, there will need to be a FK that points back to the parent Taak record. EF will need to be configured with that relationship.

```
[Key]    
public int TaakId { get; set; }
// ...
public int? ParentTaakId { get; set; }
public List<Taak> Taken { get; private set; }
```

Then when you set up the mapping either with modelBuilder or an `EntityTypeConfiguration`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Taak>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Taken)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentTaakId);
```

Lastly, why is your Werknemers collection in Taak marked as `[NotMapped]`? Since a Werknemer has a Taak reference, this mapping should be fine to configure within the entity. `[NotMapped]` values should be used sparingly, and generally avoided because the temptation will be to use them in a LINQ expression which would result in a runtime error.

Answer (score 19):

So I got this error when converting from some Framework code to some .NET Core (EF Core).  Turns out the code compiles fine with the old way:

```
myQueryable.Include(x => x.SubProp.Select(y => y.SubSubProp));
```

So watch out for that, and instead convert it (as gleaned from other answers) to the new EF Core `ThenInclude`

```
myQueryable.Include(x => x.SubProp).ThenInclude(x => x.SubSubProp);
```

Comment: `SelectMany` was never supported in `Include`. It should be `Select`.

Comment: Good call, I'll edit that typo.  Shouldn't psueocode in S.O.  :D